# Xamarin.Forms add ScrollView to ContentPage and wrap existing content

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I have a `Xamarin.Forms` page written in `.xaml` On iOS platform only I am trying to wrap the content of the page in `ScrollView` to help fix resizing issue when keyboard is shown.

The page looks something like this:

```
<base:mypagebase...>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
       ...
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
       <RelativeLayout x:Name="ViewContentLayout" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          ....
       </RelativeLayou>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</base:mypagebase>
```

I am trying in the constructor of my `mpage.xaml.cs` after `InitializeComponent()` to wrap my `RelativeLayout` in `ScrollView`

Something like this:

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    var scroll = new ScrollView();
    scroll.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical;
    scroll.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
    scroll.Content = ViewContentLayout;
    Content = scroll;
}
```

It passes through but throws exception later:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at Xamarin.Forms.RelativeLayout.OnSizeRequest (System.Double widthConstraint, System.Double heightConstraint) [0x00017] in RelativeLayout.cs:185
```

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the properties are called matters, seems like the Content root had to be set first:

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    var viewContentLayout = ViewContentLayout;
    var scroll = new ScrollView();

    Content = scroll;

    scroll.Content = viewContentLayout;          
}
```

Comment: That seems very strange. How did you figure it out?